# Defining a function in a header class with using its own struct?

Tags: c++, nested-class

```
class List{
        public:
        List();
        void add(int x);
        void remove();
        void display();
        void findingEvens(Node* n, Node* &h);
        private:
        struct Node{
                Node* next;
                int data;

        };
        Node* head;

    };
```

I have the above code in my header class, in the member function

```
void findingEvens(Node* n, Node* &h);
```

The problem is in the main class it gives an error for the following code besides I've already include the list.h,

```
    Node *result = 0;
    cout << findingEvens(l, result);
    l.display();
```

As an error it says that

`error: ‘Node’ was not declared in this scope`

But to declare it in this scope I've already include the list.h class. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

> **However the main problem is in the prototype of the function `findingEvents` it gives an error for the `Node*` however it's already defined**

You use the *type* before it seen by the compiler in the same file. So the compiler cannot understand what is `Node`
Move the function declaration after the structure is declared.

```
 public:
        List();
        void add(int x);
        void remove();
        void display();
        private:
        struct Node{
                Node* next;
                int data;

        };
        Node* head;
        void findingEvens(List::Node* n, List::Node* &h);
```

---

`Node` is a nested structure. You need to tell the compiler where to find it by using its full qualification:

```
List::Node *result = 0;
^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You need to read about **[Nested classes](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr061.htm)**.

Comment: Oh I edited that part and it worked. However in main.cpp the error continues. Besides I include list.h. I'm adding it to the question.

Comment: @Nawaz: He needs your answer now :)

Comment: @AlokSave: He needs to learn the basics first. He has got so many problems in his code. I'm not in a mood of clarifying all of them. :P

Comment: @Nawaz Oh no.. You're so cruel.

Comment: @MertCanCelik: You sure need to pick up a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @AlokSave I'm so happy for your both help and advices thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the prototype of findingEvens to be after the definition of `struct Node`.  You should remove the `private:` for now.

Comment: what's the problem with `private`?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to have a public method where one of the parameters has a type that is private.  C++ might disallow that, so I was warning him about it.

Comment: Yep, or alternatively move the `struct Node` to `public`.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not really useful anymore, but here the fixed code:

```
class List{
public:
    List();
    void add(int x);
    void remove();
    void display();

    struct Node {
        struct Node* next;
        int data;
    };

    void findingEvens(Node* n, Node* &h);
private:
    Node* head;
};
```

Comment: Well I learn one thing today : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c